# Magento Data flow Advanced Profiles

Tags: magento, import, export, configurable-product

I have tried dataflow Advanced Profiles in magento but only able to import simple products. Not able to import configurable products. can any one help me with solution. I have googled it and tried 2 3 tricks but unable to do it. even installed AMartinez_CustomImportExport but dont know how to run it. please help.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/importing-configurable-products

also check this link 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33963/import-configurable-products-csv

This link has comments related to importing configurable product.

Comment: already saw but still have problem in importing configurable products in magento backend. I want solution for advance profile imports